# smtp, hidden 'rcpt to' value

Tags: email, smtp

received an email from a spammer addressed to a non-existent user in my domain, let's call it example.com. obviously the headers had been spoofed but i must assume the 'rcpt to' field was legit for it to reach me. i have all messages forwarded to my gmail from my domain's sendmail.

trouble is nothing in the message source in gmail is showing which of my the legit email addresses the spammer specified to reach me. all i see in the message source is the bogus email. i can't reproduce this either. this is the first 'received from' part:

```
> Received: from SQSZJWGPY ([1.52.114.198]) 
> by example.com (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id s5PEIUCI003583;
> Wed, 25 Jun 2014 10:18:31 -0400
```

in all other emails the last line looks something like this:

```
for me@example.com; Wed, 25 Jun 2014 10:32:11 -0400
```

so the legit email is revealed. i know the envelope is not included in the message source but there must be a way to find out what the 'rcpt to' value was without going into sendmail logging and what not. how did the spammer hide the email he specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after much testing and trial and error i have found the answer to my own question. bear in mind that i use sendmail 8.14.4 (5 years old) and i haven't done much tweaking to the sendmail.mc file.

if during the smtp session the sender specifies a non-existent account in the 'rcpt to' line followed by a valid one, the recipient's address is masked in the headers. e.g.

```
mail from: spammer@example.com
250 2.1.0 spammer@example.com... Sender ok
rcpt to: bad
550 5.1.1 bad... User unknown
rcpt to: good
250 2.1.5 good... Recipient ok
data
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
looks good?
.
250 2.0.0 s5UHeBOj004847 Message accepted for delivery
```

the message arrives to user 'good' and nowhere in the header (or elsewhere in the message) it is indicated that it was sent to 'good'.

maybe spammers are doing this accidentally or deliberately, but they are doing it and this  can be reproduced every time using above method, at least with my sendmail version.

that's all

Comment: This is because multiple recipients (not just bad ones) for one message (headers+body) would spill the potential BCC information. The alternative is to insert a different header for each rcpt, and that can be expensive to queue.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of an email message, specifically, the `to`, `cc` and `from` headers, don't necessarily correspond to the envelope `mail from` and `rcpt to` of the message.  The SMTP protocol, specified in [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), is where the envelope data is sent.

The message contents, specified in RFC 5322, contain the message headers and message body.  The headers are where you find the `to`, `cc` and `from` headers that we usually use to identify out who sent the message and who else received the message.

However, there is nothing requiring that the `from`, `to` and `cc` headers match to the envelope `mail from` or `rcpt to`, though well behaved mail software will often have the association made clear.  I say "often" because, for example, when you blind carbon copy (BCC) somebody on your message, your mail client will not include these recipients in the `to` or `cc` headers.

In your case, the `rcpt to` specified to sendmail is not put into a header by default, so is probably lost.  If you really don't want to look into the sendmail logs you are probably out of luck for this one message.

If you expect you will continue to receive similar messages you could [instruct sendmail to add the envelope rcpt to into a header](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/faq_ver_8_issues/#3.29).  Then, without looking at the sendmail logs, you will have the rcpt to in a `X-Envelope-To` header.

Answer (score 0):

The spammer probably has a SMTP server where he has a email account configured as administrator, then he probably can send emails from different senders. The SMTP server probably doesn't have some filters to control the output and input emails, then if you are an administrator of this server, you can send emails from sender like "example@yahoo.com" even if your domain name isn't yahoo.com. Once, some partners and I did a test in a company (customer) to demonstrate that their SMTP server can be victim from a phishing attack, we could send emails from different senders with different domain name.

I hope this information to help you.

Good luck.